# Twilio How to do pagination with messages?

Tags: pagination, twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api

I am able to get the messages from the new php client. How do I do pagination with messages? How to get next_uri, first_uri, page_size parameters ?

```
 <?php 
 require_once '/Twilio/autoload.php'; // Loads the library

 use Twilio\Rest\Client;

 // Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
 $sid = "xxx"; 
 $token = "xxx";
 $client = new Client($sid, $token);

 // Loop over the list of messages and echo a property for each one
 foreach ($client->messages->read() as $message) {
 echo $message->body;
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Instead of using `read()` you can use [`stream()`](https://twilio.github.io/twilio-php/class-Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account.MessageList.html#_stream) which will return an iterator for your messages. You can give `stream()` a limit, but by default it has no limit and will iterate over all of your messages.

```
 <?php 
 require_once '/Twilio/autoload.php'; // Loads the library

 use Twilio\Rest\Client;

 // Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
 $sid = "xxx"; 
 $token = "xxx";
 $client = new Client($sid, $token);

 // Loop over the list of messages and echo a property for each one
 foreach ($client->messages->stream() as $message) {
 echo $message->body;
 }
 ?>
```

The [pagination information](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/response#response-formats-list-paging-information) itself is returned in each request. You can see an [example of a call to the `Calls` resource in the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/response#response-formats-list-paging-information) and the pagination information will be the same for `Messages`.

Comment: Where can I get the documentation on the methods read(), stream() ?

Comment: You can find them in the PHP documentation here: https://twilio.github.io/twilio-php/class-Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account.MessageList.html#_stream

Comment: The Twilio page provided by @philnash is no longer there. 404

Comment: Apologies for the 404. The docs are now here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/reference/twilio-php/5.16.2/class-Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account.MessageList.html

Comment: @philnash I am able to get the records by stream function and also getting the next page information. But I am not sure how can I call next page ? can you help me?

Comment: or there is anyway to pass the page number in stream function.

Comment: The next page information should give you a URL for the next page of results. You can use that URL with the [`getPage`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/reference/twilio-php/5.16.2/class-Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account.MessageList.html#_getPage) method.

Answer (score 2):

I wasted hours on this.  In case it saves some future person some time, here's what I did.  I'm using Laravel but you get the idea:

In your controller:

```php
// If no pagination info has been specified, get the first page of data
// using page().  If there is pagination info in the request, use it with
// getPage()

if (! $request->page) {
    $messages = $client->messages->page([], 30);
} else {
    $messages = $client->messages->getPage($request->page);
}
```

Then, in your view (Laravel/blade pseudo-code):

```php
@foreach ($messages as $message)
    $message->body
    // ... etc
@endforeach

// Next page link
?page={{ urlencode($messages->getNextPageUrl()) }}

// Prev page link
?page={{ urlencode($messages->getPreviousPageUrl()) }}
```

[Docs for `page()` and `getPage()`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/reference/twilio-php/5.16.2/class-Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account.MessageList.html).

Comment: Looking back at this question posted 6 years ago, I still don't find a proper example in the entire Twilio documentation that can show me how to achieve this, I have wasted many hours.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Node.js code for fetching message history using paging. You can specify how many items should be in a single page by using the parameter **pageSize** and use **limit** parameter to limit the number of pages to display

```js
              client.messages.each({
                dateSent: new Date(date.toDateString()),
                from: event.To,
                to: event.From,
                pageSize: 1,
                limit:1,
                done: function(done) {//this is the call back for the for each loop. this will get fired even if no messages found.
                    console.log('completed for each');
                }
            }, (messages) => {//each message can handle here.
                console.log("message body:", messages.body);
            }, (Error) => {
                console.log('err');
     });
```