# How to pagination TWILIO Conversations and its messages in PHP?

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-conversations

I am having issues in paginating the TWILIO Conversations and Its messages. I have tried to paginate but all the pages are giving same results. Can someone please help ?

```
$conversations = $twilio
    ->conversations
    ->v1
    ->services(TWILIO_CHAT_SERVICE_SID)
    ->conversations
    ->read($page_size, $page);
```

Comment: What is the code you are using so far?

Comment: Hi @philnash I am using this code for showing the conversation listings into the chat.

Comment: I don't see any code, can you edit your question with the code, please?

Comment: Hi @philnash I have edited the code into the question now.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41546026/28376) is the same, just for a different resource. Pagination works the same across all Twilio API resources. Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41546026/28376